# Were contractions used in 1800

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Were contractions used in conversational English in 1800 to 1820? For example: it's, don't, aren't,...

Comment: Spoken English has always used contractions. Always. In every era.

Comment: 'Tis true. Contractions have e'er been present.

Comment: This question is trivially answered by using the [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED quotes " All want to go to town..—four horses, three mules, and a jack ass—can't carry 'em all." from 1811.

Contractions like "can't" were not often written in those days, so it seems likely that "can't" had been around for quite a few years before that.

**Edit**: I should have looked further down the page. The OED also quotes " What can I have done with my Papers?..Highty-tighty! I can't have left 'em at home." from 1781.

So certainly, "can't" (at least) was in use by 1800, and probably rather earlier.